# Get count of related rows in postgres with existing lateral join

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, lateral-join

This query gives me several rows from `table1` along with the related records from `table2` using `left join lateral`. I've limited the rows from table2 to 10 rows each.

```
select t1.id, array_agg(t2.column1) 
from table1 t1 
left join lateral (select * from table2 where table1_id = t1.id order by column2 limit 10) t2 on true 
where t1.other = other_value
group by t1.id
```

But how can I include the total `count(*)` of all records in table2 related to table1 (`select count(*) from table2 where table1_id = t1.id`). Since I'm doing a lateral join I'm not sure how I would add these results.

Could I reuse the lateral join I'm already doing, or would I have to do a separate lateral join because the first one has a `limit 10` and the `count(*)` requires no limit? What should the query look like to make it work like this? (I think there might be a way to do it using the array slice syntax from the first lateral join but I think that would be expensive since it would have to get all the rows just to get a count of them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well use window functions for this:

```
select t1.id, array_agg(t2.column1) 
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*, count(*) over (partition by table1_id) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by table1_id order by column2) as seqnum
      from table2
     ) t2
     on t2.table1_id = t1.id and sequm <= 10
where t1.other = other_value 
group by t1.id;
```

You could do this as a separate `lateral join`.

EDIT:

With a separate lateral join:

```
select t1.id, array_agg(t2.column1), t2c.cnt
from table1 t1 left join lateral
     (select *
      from table2
      where table1_id = t1.id
      order by column2
      limit 10
     ) t2
     on true left join lateral
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from table2
      where table1_id = t1.id
     ) t2c
     on true
where t1.other = other_value
group by t1.id, t2.cnt;
```

Or with a single lateral join with no aggregation in the outer query:

```
select t1.id, t2.column1s, t2.cnt
from table1 t1 left join lateral
     (select array_agg(t2.column1) as column1, max(cnt) as cnt
      from (select t2.*,
                   row_number() over (order by column2 desc) as seqnum,
                   count(*) over () as cnt
            from table2
            where table1_id = t1.id
           ) t2
      where seqnum <= 10
     ) t2
     on true left join 
where t1.other = other_value;
```

This is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thanks, could you also please show the way to do it with a separate lateral join?

Comment: Does the second query require `t2c.cnt` in the `group by`?

Comment: @user779159 . . . Yes.